# Как организовать базу данных с книгами?

Tags: sqlite, реляционная-модель

Новичок. Мне необходимо создать БД с книгами/комиксами. Но не могу понять то, как это можно огранизовать. Пример. Мне нужно взять книгу и связать с ней все её части. Чтобы при её поиске тут же можно было увидеть всё необходимое: части, ссылки на магазины и цены. Но в одну строку вместе с названием книги можно добавить лишь по одному значению в каждый столбец. Саму программу собираюсь писать на Python, если это играет какую-то роль.
Заранее благодарю.

Comment: В таблице книги можно хранить числовое поле -- номер в серии (если у книги нет серии, то это может быть NULL), и id самой серии, соответственно, чтобы получить следующую книгу из серии от текущей книги нужно сделать select по id серии и номер серии + 1

Answer (score 2):

Если речь идет о частях книги/комикса, то можно поступить одним из следующих вариантов:

1. Не очень гибкий но простой. Держать в таблице описывающей книгу отдельное поле с указателем на следующую часть этой же книги изданную тем же издательством (то есть просто создать что-то типа поля next, которое ссылается на первичный ключ той же таблицы), при этом можно так же создать дополнительное поле prev в котором хранить ссылку на предыдущую часть этой книги. Но циклические связи возможно трудны будут при написании кода.
2. Более гибкий вариант: сделать отдельно таблицу для хранения информации о сериях книг, а потом связью многие ко многим связать эту таблицу с таблицей книг.

Опять же эти оба варианта могут использоваться одновременно в приложении и дополнять друг-друга в разных ситуациях.